# Translucent shader ignores alpha channel

Tags: node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I want to make a simple tree following [this tutorial][1], but when I add a translucent shader it ignores alpha transparency and I can see texture planes. how can I fix it?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

UPD - answer below works, but also the original approach from this tutorial works with Cycles (not Eevee).
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7PdiGXbrD0&ab_channel=CGGeek
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHjKL.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Add Shader* is probably not what you're looking for, it probably adds the datas, plus you can't plug your alpha mask (that's why your alpha channel is ignored). What you could try is a *Translucent* and a *Transparent* mixed into a *Mix Shader* (also, maybe try to mix your *Translucent* itself with a *Transparent* before mixing it):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think the problem is that I used Eevee, probably this tutorial designed for Cycles. The approach you described works well, but it makes leaves a little darker, using Add shader somehow makes them a little brighter. Thank you again!

Comment: @Rumata You can use Hue/Saturation or RGB Curves to pump up the colors a little.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue even while using it in cycles. What worked for me was that I mixed the translucent and transparent and then mixed that result with Principle. This worked for me:

[image: Node group]

[image: Final result]